# How to force new line inside a table in Haddock (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, haddock

I need to make some documentation with a table that has a cell with two lines (It's code, so it needs to be on separated lines). However if I try

```
   {-
    +----------+------------------+
    |   Col1   |       Col2       |
    +==========+==================+
    | One line | This should span |
    |          | Two lines        |
    +----------+------------------+
   -}
```

It gives the same result as using

```
{-
+----------+---------------------------+
|   Col1   |           Col2            |
+==========+===========================+
| One line | This should spanTwo lines |
+----------+---------------------------+
-}
```

Is there a way to force a new line?

---

More importantly, what about code inside the table? Can I make it multiline?

Obviously this doesn't work

```
   {-
    +----------+------------------+
    |   Col1   |       Col2       |
    +==========+==================+
    | One line | @This is code    |
    |          |  Other code line@|
    +----------+------------------+
   -}
```

The following works but, again, produces a cell with only one line:

```
   {-
    +----------+------------------+
    |   Col1   |       Col2       |
    +==========+==================+
    | One line | @This is code@   |
    |          | @Other code line@|
    +----------+------------------+
   -}
```